# How to dynamically update the shields on github based on builds and test results?

Tags: jenkins, github, continuous-integration, shields.io

I have a project listed on github and I want to setup a CI and automated test system where the badges like the following are automatically posted as comments on the pull requests, so that I can decide the quality of the code submitted and its impact :

[image: Travis]

I came across a similar and nice service called [shields.io](https://github.com/badges/shields) where they are giving `.svg` icons. Hence, rendering will also be perfect.

Now, I am confused as how to get this thing integrated as per my plans. As I can understand is that the badges are simple links to some server, which serves these images. All I need to post is the link to these badges in the comment section of coming pull requests.

So, what i can do is i can create my own server on some port and post URLs to my server (corresponding to each icon) as comment on the github pull requests and Github will simply display these badges. So for each badge, I will have one URL to my server.

But how will i manage icons like

[image: Jenkins coverage]

1. For 0 to 100%, shall i create 100 such files on my server?
2. Or is my approach not correct? If yes, please suggest a better way or how other are doing in production environments?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at [anybadge](https://pypi.org/project/anybadge).  You can programmatically generate badges, set custom thresholds for choosing colors based on results or set fixed colors. It's a small light-weight python app which keeps things simple. You can generate the SVG text and embed that direct into your posts.

The main reason I use this package is because my production servers are fire-walled with no external internet access, and I can't (and don't want to) be hitting external URLs to generate badges.

If you want to run your own server it can also do that. After pip installing, you can run `anybadge-server` to run a local webserver.

```
> anybadge-server
2020-03-20 08:39:09,434 INFO:anybadge_server.py(154):main: Starting up anybadge server.
2020-03-20 08:39:09,441 INFO:anybadge_server.py(112):run: Serving at: http://localhost:8000
```

[image: anybadge web server]

The result is:

[image: example badge]